# mysql_num_rows doesn't work (will not return 0)

Tags: mysql, sql, zero, string

I have created a condition in which if a query returns a result, it would execute a code and would return 1 or more. However if the query is empty, we would get 0 and the if statement would not activate.

However I have been getting 1 and the if statement activates despite the fact that no rows are returning (tested it out in a phpmyadmin SQL executor.

One hint is that it says that 'Your SQL query has been executed successfully' while no rows return instead if saying 'MySQL returned an empty result set'.

What is happening and how do I fix this?

```
$search_num_rows_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT tags_movie.name_movie, tags_game.name_game, tags_sport.name_sport, tags_music.name_music, tags_show.name_show FROM tags_game, tags_movie, tags_sport, tags_music, tags_show WHERE tags_game.relation = '$user_id' && tags_movie.relation = '$user_id' && tags_sport.relation = '$user_id' && tags_music.relation = '$user_id' && tags_show.relation = '$user_id') somealias WHERE name_movie LIKE '{$movie}%' && name_game LIKE '{$name_game}%' &&name_sport LIKE '{$sport}%' &&name_music LIKE '{$music}%' && name_show LIKE '{$show}%'");

$number = mysql_num_rows($search_num_rows_2);
echo $number;
if ($number != 0){

    }
```

Comment: That means you have no result for that WHERE conditions, try to remove WHERE part and see if there is anything you get as output.

Comment: Removed the WHERE condition right at the end, but it still says the query was successfully executed. If there is a row, it displays it but if there is nothing, it doesn't say that it is empty.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $number;` ?

Comment: The output is always one, whether or not rows return or not.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try it

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you didn't implement to catch empty result in your `if` block and it should be like,

```
if ($number != 0){
   echo $number;
} else {
   echo 'Empty result';
}
```

**EDIT 1**

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT tags_movie.name_movie, tags_game.name_game, tags_sport.name_sport, tags_music.name_music, tags_show.name_show FROM tags_game, tags_movie, tags_sport, tags_music, tags_show WHERE tags_game.relation = '$user_id' && tags_movie.relation = '$user_id' && tags_sport.relation = '$user_id' && tags_music.relation = '$user_id' && tags_show.relation = '$user_id') somealias WHERE name_movie LIKE '{$movie}%' && name_game LIKE '{$name_game}%' &&name_sport LIKE '{$sport}%' &&name_music LIKE '{$music}%' && name_show LIKE '{$show}%'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($res);
if (count($data) > 0){
       print_r($data);
} else {
       echo 'Empty result';
}
```